# I can't find file `supp-mis.tex

Tags: errors, packages

As I was to compile using MikTeX and TeXstudio I got the message:

```
"I can't find file 'supp-mis.tex'. \input supp-mis.tex
Emergency stop. \input supp-mis.tex
Option `pagecolor' is not available anymore."
```

Please, how do I correct this error?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: the file has been called `supp-mis.mkii` for some years, you must have a very old version of `pdftex.def` in your path?

Answer (score 2):

### Option `pagecolor`

The latter part

```
Option `pagecolor' is not available anymore
```

is a warning from package `hyperref` about an unused option.
The warning can be removed by removing the option setting `pagecolor`.

### Missing `supp-mis.tex`

The file `supp-mis.tex` was renamed to `supp-mis.mkii`.
TeX Live contains the file `supp-mis.tex` with the following contents:

```
% This file is not needed, for instance supp-pdf has the relevant code
% built in and ppchtex is adapted.

\input supp-mis.mkii
```

You can try, if your TeX document compiles, if you have provided this file.
It might also be possible, that the TeX distribution needs an update.